# Value not changing even after passing it through a function

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

How do I get the value inside a function to be displayed inside the main function as well? I tried doing the following but output_size is always 0 instead of 64

```
void convert_to_gibberish(const char * input, const unsigned int input_size, char** output, unsigned int * output_size){ 

 

// do some encryption 

 

DWORD gibberish_text_size = 64; // Constant value obtained from encryption functions 

output_size = (unsigned int *)gibberish_text_size ; 

 

} 

 

int main(){ 

char * test = "test" 

char * output = NULL; 

unsigned int output_size = 0; 

convert_to_gibberish(test,strlen(test),&output, &output_size); 

cout << "Output size:" << output_size << endl; 

}
```

Comment: `*output_size = gibberish_text_size;` makes more sense.

Comment: parameters are passed by value, pointers are no exception

Answer (score 1):

You're using C++ as if it's C.

Stop using `char*`, it's `const char*`, and even then stop using it and use `std::string`.

Stop using (double) pointers `**` to pass by reference, use `&` instead, actual references.

Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

The problem with your code is that you aren't dereferencing the pointer to assign its value, rather you're assigning it a (wrong) address. Do it like:

```
*output_size = gibberish_text_size;
```

Modernizing your code:

```
void convert_to_gibberish(const std::string& input, 
const unsigned int input_size, std::string& output, unsigned int& output_size)
{ 

    // do some encryption 


    DWORD gibberish_text_size = 64; // Constant value obtained from  encryption functions 

    output_size = gibberish_text_size ; 
} 

int main(){ 

    std::string test = "test" 

    std::string output;

    unsigned int output_size = 0; 

    convert_to_gibberish(test, test.length(), output, output_size); 

    cout << "Output size:" << output_size << endl; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your function return an `int` instead of `void` and end the function with `return output_size;`.

Then in `main()` you can do:

```
cout << "Output size:" << convert_to_gibberish(test,strlen(test),&output, &output_size) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have committed 2 errors. the errors are this line

`output_size = (unsigned int *)gibberish_text_size ;`

The first one you convert a DWORD that is an `unsigned int` and not a `unsigned int *`, so the cast is not what you expect.
The second error is assign a pointer to a variable that is in the scope of the function. This cause that the pointer point to a variable out of the scope, so you can have crash or false result.

The correct syntax to do what you want to do is the following:

```
void convert_to_gibberish(const char * input, const unsigned int input_size, char** output, unsigned int * output_size){ 

 

// do some encryption 

 

DWORD gibberish_text_size = 64; // Constant value obtained from encryption functions 

*output_size = gibberish_text_size ; 

 

} 

 

int main(){ 

char * test = "test" 

char * output = NULL; 

unsigned int output_size = 0; 

convert_to_gibberish(test,strlen(test),&output, &output_size); 

cout << "Output size:" << output_size << endl; 

}
```

But this when you use C++ is not the best way... you can use reference `&` instead of pointers in this way:

```
void convert_to_gibberish(const char  *input, const unsigned int input_size, char* &output, unsigned int  &output_size){ 

 

// do some encryption 

 

DWORD gibberish_text_size = 64; // Constant value obtained from encryption functions 

output_size = gibberish_text_size ; 

 

} 

 

int main(){ 

char * test = "test" 

char * output = NULL; 

unsigned int output_size = 0; 

convert_to_gibberish(test,strlen(test),output, output_size); 

cout << "Output size:" << output_size << endl; 

}
```